# Form Tag Placement

Tags: html

I have a list of images:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="m.jpg">
        <span class="file-data">img name</span>
    </li>
    //etc
```

When a user drags a new image to the window, a preview of the image is displayed and along with a few field inputs.

My question concerns the form element tag.

So far my HTML looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <form>
        <li>
            <img src="m.jpg">
            <div class="file-data">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Alt">
                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Keywords">
            </div>
        </li>
        <div id="btn-container">
            <button class="">Cancel</button>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- li from above example -->
    <li>
       <img src="m.jpg">
       <span class="file-data">img name</span>
    </li>
    //etc
```

Here is what happens:

1. form li is hidden
2. User drags image to browser
3. form li is cloned with image preview shown
4. user enters data
5. form saved via ajax

What is the best placement of the form tag? Can I put it inside ul?

Comment: The form element should be outside the UL. It should be the parent to your form elements.

Comment: Thanks, but then I'll have stuff in my form that is nothing to do with the form - the list of images tht already exist.

Comment: What you have inside your form tag for "extra stuff" doesnt make any difference. It doesnt make sense to add a form tag between a UL.

Comment: Adding to Epik, if there will be be multiple pictures, you can use fieldsets or an ul for each img. Don't forget the placeholder attribute is not equivalent to a label tag, so those inputs are not accessible

Comment: I'm still unsure of your method, im going to have a form with a few inputs in and potentially hundreds of li's that are nothing to do  with the form - surely thsi si not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form having lots of content is not a problem here. According to the [HTML4 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-FORM)

> The FORM element acts as a container for controls. It specifies:
>
> - The layout of the form (given by the contents of the element).
> - The program that will handle the completed and submitted form (the action attribute). The receiving program must be able to parse
>     name/value pairs in order to make use of them.
> - The method by which user data will be sent to the server (the method attribute).
> - A character encoding that must be accepted by the server in order to handle this form (the accept-charset attribute). User agents may
>     advise the user of the value of the accept-charset attribute and/or
>     restrict the user's ability to enter unrecognized characters.
>
> *A formcan contain text and markup (paragraphs, **lists**, etc.) in
>   addition to form controls.*

[HTML5 candidate recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) says:

> #### The form element
>
> **Content model:**
>   Flow content, but with **no form element** descendants.

Thus you can have whatever you want within a form element, though as a corner case you cannot have another form inside.

However, the `<ul></ul>` should have only `<li>` elements as the direct descendants! If you intend to have 1 form for each item in the list, then naturally these forms must be fully contained inside the `<li>` element; the code in your second listing is not quite right.